# Python/Pyapns issue with APNS server connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, apple-push-notifications

We are using the pyapns to publish notification to Apple. Having developed PEM files for our development and production systems, using the method demonstrated in: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/ we have got the development system working. However the production system always comes up with:

> Fault 500: 'Connection to the APNS server could not be made.'

We have tested that the pem file works using:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

and it holds the connection

The one difference between the dev and prod systems (besides the pem files) is how we create the provision:

```
provision(apns_provision, apns_provision).read(), 'sandbox')
```

However when we use the production pem file and use the code:

```
provision(apns_provision, apns_provision).read(), 'production')
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks